# Dynkin generated system

Tags: measure-theory

source: http://www.probability.net/SOLdynkin.pdf

This is for self study.

I am trying to follow the solution to problem 6 (i) page 16. Problem  is on page 4.

It says $A\in \mathcal A$, and $B \in \mathcal A$. $\mathcal D(\mathcal A)$ being the Dynkin system generated by $\mathcal A$, $\mathcal A \subseteq \mathcal D(\mathcal A)$. I completely understand this part.

Then it says in particular $B\in \mathcal D(\mathcal A)$. I don't understand this. Why should an element of $\mathcal A$ be an element of $\mathcal D(\mathcal A)$ as well?

I make up this example. For $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\mathcal A=\{1,2\}$, we have $\mathcal D(\mathcal A) = \{\emptyset, \{1,2\}, \{3,4\}, \Omega\}$. Clearly $\mathcal A \subseteq \mathcal D(\mathcal A)$ but the statement $1 \in \mathcal D(\mathcal A)$ or $2 \in \mathcal D(\mathcal A)$ is false. While it is true that $1 \in \mathcal A$ and $2 \in \mathcal A$.

What did i miss? I am sure I am misunderstanding something, in that case could somebody explain why every element of $\mathcal A$ should be an element of $\mathcal D(\mathcal A)$ necessarily?

Comment: When you write $A\subset B$, you already mean that any element of $A$ is also in $B$. Here, both $A$ and $D(A)$ are sets of sets. (So their elements are sets.) It should be understood like that.

Comment: thanks @kolobokish. In that case how would you change the example I gave to accommodate it and make it right?

Comment: In your case, your $A$ should be $\{\{1,2\}\}$. So it is the set of one set, for example. And later constructions, is exactly the same. Or you can take for example $A$ to be like these, $A=\{\{1\},\{1,2\}\}$, and later use the properties of Dynkin system and construct it.)

Comment: Thanks. This makes perfect sense now!